# Is there any way to disconnect a client connection of socket.io in the server.js?

Tags: socket.io, disconnect

I know the client part may use disconnect method to disconnect a client connection.
but I can't find any way to disconnect from the server part.

```
socket.on('connection', function(client) {

    client.on('message', function(message) {
                var sessionId = message.disId;
        socket.disconnect(sessionId);//to disconnect another client
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server can kick a particular client by using either of these methods:

`client._onDisconnect();`

(or)

`socket.clients[kickedUserSocketId].onDisconnect();`

*Credit to SeanColombo on [GitHub](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/47#issuecomment-966713)*

Comment: @BMiner I'm not sure if the Socket.IO API has changed since then. Maybe contacting LearnBoost would help?

Comment: Is it still working? I use Socket.io 0.9.6 My app's worker sometimes crash right after kicking IP from my banned list. Here more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125870/node-js-0-8-8-socket-io-0-9-6-kick-socket